# Is using "what he claims is" in this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> "He is on hunger strike in protest at what he claims is his wrongful conviction for murder."

This is an example sentence for the word '[wrongful](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wrongful)' I come across in Collins dictionary.

I don't understand the '*what he claims is*' part in the sentence, to me, the whole sentence should be like

- "He is on hunger strike in protest at his wrongful conviction for murder."

or

- "He is on hunger strike in protest at *what he claims of* his wrongful conviction for murder."

If the original sentence is grammatically correct, can anybody tell me how the sentence is structured from the grammatical point of view, especially for the 'what he claims is' part?

Comment: I’d say protest *over* instead of *at*.

Comment: I'd say that this is a 'fused' relative construction where "what he claims is his wrongful conviction for murder" is a noun phrase functioning as complement of the preposition "at". The fusion is in the word "what", which functions simultaneously as antecedent (head of the NP) and relativised element. Think of it as "that which he claims is his wrongful conviction for murder".

Comment: "He is on hunger strike in protest at his conviction for murder (which, he claims, **is** a wrongful one)."

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your reply! I'm wondering now is this 'fused' relative construction common in English, Could you give me more similar examples ?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thanks for your reply! Your paraphrase is clear. I'd also like to make a minor change to the sentence like this: He is on hunger strike in protest at, what he claims is, his wrongful conviction for murder. but I don't know whether it is correct.

Comment: The phrase is not usually separated between commas like that.

Comment: Please see my previous comment for how the fusion works grammatically. Other examples include "I ate what you gave me" (meaning "I ate that which you gave me") / "Whoever said that was mistaken" (meaning "The person who said that was mistaken").

Comment: << He is on hunger strike in protest at (what he claims is) his wrongful conviction for murder. >> This shows an arguably correct parenthetical interpretation, though the original doesn't have the same emphasis or hint of scepticism. << He is on hunger strike in protest at his wrongful (as he sees it) conviction for murder. >> shows a very similar concessive (conceding that the defendant's label 'wrongful' may be inaccurate) parenthetical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Could it also be parsed as << He is on hunger strike in protest at what (he claims) is his wrongful conviction >>? "he claims" is a qualifier that indicates that the characterization is not universally accepted, but only his claim.

Comment: @Barmar I suspect you know it could. It's a modal marker (a parenthetical expressing the possibility that the statement being written is in some way inaccurate) stressing, as you say, 'this is what _he_ claims').